# Google Analytics gtag event triggered before page reload, does not work on iPhone

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, gtag.js

I'm using Google Analytics (gtag.js) on a website, and I'm trying to send events.

I have an 'Add to cart' button, a simple `<a class="ga-add-to-cart">Buy me!</a>` element.

On click of this button, I'm firing the `gtag('event' ... )` method:

```
$('.ga-add-to-cart').click(function(){

    productName = 'something';
    price = 123;

    gtag('event', 'add_to_cart', {
        'event_category': 'ecommerce',
        'event_label': productName,
        'value': price
    });
});
```

This is documented by Google [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events).

Of course, because I'm using an `<a>` tag for my button, the page is reloading after it's clicked. There's a race condition for the page reload and the `gtag` event.

But it's working fine when triggered in a desktop browser - I can see the HTTP request in my console and the events in Google Analytics.

However when on an iPhone, Safari browser, the event is not triggered. When inspecting the phone via desktop Safari I'm seeing that the HTTP request is cancelled.

I'm clearly doing something wrong here.

What's the best way to fire this event before page (re)load?

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly setting the transport mechanism to use beacon sends.

Modify your code to use the following:

```
$('.ga-add-to-cart').click(function(){

    productName = 'something';
    price = 123;

    gtag('event', 'add_to_cart', {
        'transport_type': 'beacon', // Newly introduced code
        'event_category': 'ecommerce',
        'event_label': productName,
        'value': price
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks vinoaj, unfortunately this hasn't helped - I'm still seeing a cancelled request to https://www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ua/ec.js when firing the `gtag('event'...)` function on an iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so perhaps I was Googling the wrong thing. Found some helpful info here...

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/sending-data#implement_event_callback_functions

....which gives examples of the callback on the `gtag('event' ...)` method.

I think my solution is to either

- Use the callback to delay the default action of my `<a>`, or;
- Fire the `gtag('event' ...)` on the other side of the page reload